# Bluetooth service starts too late, so I can't use my mouse on the login screen. How can I fix this?

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, lightdm

I have a problem with my Bluetooth mouse (Microsoft Sculpt Comfort mouse) on my MacbookPro 13 inch. I updated to 18.04 and most of the problems went away. The mouse works fine once I get the desktop running. But it does not work at all on the login screen.

Is there any way to start the Bluetooth service early in the boot process so I have the mouse available for login?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable bluetooth at startup 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938228/how-to-enable-bluetooth-at-startup-16-04-lts)