# Login with my bluetooth keyboard ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bash, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth keyboard paired with my laptop. When I reboot a system and get to a login page, I'm not able to use it. Bluetooth isn't active. I've researched the question and [found out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20588/how-to-make-bt-keyboard-available-at-login-and-os-selection-screens) I have to have `blues` package installed. Still I stuck on how to script an installation of `blues` and all its settings on bash.

Are there any alternative ways to enable bluetooth on a login page from terminal?

Or how can I script an installation of `blues` and all its settings on bash?

Comment: The program is called "bluez" and not "blues" so try installing it if it is not already installed . `sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-tools` You may need additional packages, I am not sure, `sudo apt-get install bluez-utils bulez-compat`. For a full list see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bluez

Comment: If that fails, see, in order, https://askubuntu.com/questions/522042/enable-bluetooth-at-startup-on-14-04 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/938228/how-to-enable-bluetooth-at-startup-16-04-lts and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup#Connect_Devices_at_Startup

Comment: Read my answer on another question to see how I did it on 16.04 (with the help of other fellow Ubuntu users of course): https://askubuntu.com/a/1023532/815371